# React immutability helper error?

Tags: reactjs, immutability

Full code here: https://github.com/dtdimart/hipaa-checker

This has had me stuck for hours. What is essentially a reproduction of an older version of this React based Quiz app. The app compiles without errors, but when an answer is clicked, it throws an error

```
Cannot read property '**depends on answer picked**' of undefined
```

I'm convinced the error is stemming from the 'update' portion of:

```
    setUserAnswer(answer) {
    const updatedAnswersCount = update(this.state.answersCount, {
        [answer]: { $apply: currentValue => currentValue + 1 }
    });

    this.setState({
        answersCount: updatedAnswersCount,
        answer: answer
    });
}
```

For update, I am using immutability-helper instead of the legacy react-addons-update:

```
import update from "immutability-helper";
```

The main error references the immutability helper code itself, specifically:

```
var nextValueForKey =
    type(object) === 'Map'
       ? update(object.get(key), spec[key])
       : update(object[key], spec[key]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this should be the last step in my apps functionality before moving on to customization/ appearance.

Could it be a bind issue? Constructor is:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        counter: 0,
        questionId: 1,
        question: "",
        answerOptions: [],
        answer: "",
        answerCount: {
            NonCompliant: 0,
            Compliant: 0,
            NeedsAttention: 0
        },
        result: ""
    };
    this.handleAnswerSelected = this.handleAnswerSelected.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of the state before the update?

Comment: Are you sure this is correctly binded in your method?

Comment: Axnyff, it is an empty string

Comment: As for the bind, that was another concern of mine, I'll update the question with my constructor

Comment: So this.state.answersCount is undefined and does not have a `[answer]` property then ?

Comment: okay so your comment 100% helped me spot a simple typo. 'I had 'answerCount' (no s) instead of 'answersCount'. thanks a bunch. Feel free to post that as an answer so I can mark it accepted for you!